# What is the alternative to 'getApplicationContext()' in Android for Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-navigation

I want to create a generic public method navigate the application to login screen if any response is: `unauthenticated`.

The problem is I don't have the `context` to use it in my `Navigator`.

In **Android** I used to use: `getApplicationContext()`, how can I do that in **Flutter**?

Comment: you can use the BuildContext to pass the context where ever you want

Comment: can you post code where you are trying to use the `Navigator`?

Answer (score 1):

**It will work as context** below method is a custom method

```
 Widget profileTextView(BuildContext context) {  
      }
```

Happy New Year :)

Comment: I used something like that, but it still not equivalent to "getApplicationContext()", it's another way to apply this method.

Flutter don't have a method does that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `flutter_modular` packages you can manage your application status, routes and many other things. But what interests us in this case is the context in the entire application with the following command:
`Modular.to.navigator.context`

Remembering that for routes, using this package you don't need the context, but if you need it anywhere this command above solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

In Dart, we do not often use getter and setters. In Java you are using `getApplicationContext()` for getting the `Context`. In flutter you can directly use the predefined `Context` variable anywhere inside the app as follows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
}
```

BuildContext we can use as the Application `Context`.